# HTML5 text field not validating properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have a survey that 'Onclick' should validate required fields are filled, store to local storage, and nav to confirm page. When 1 required isn't filled it works and doesn't store locally however it doesn't prompt the user which field needs to be filled. So technically it's validating just not prompting the user the way it's suppose to.

Currently:

```
<label>Hospital*:</label>
<input required title="Hospital is required!" name="MainHospital" type="text" />
```

js

```
     function clicked() {
   if (confirm('Are you sure you want to submit? You will not be able to go back.')) {
        form.submit();

   } else {
       return false;
   }
}

 $('form').submit(function() {
    var person = $("#FirstName").val() + "." + $('#LastName').val();
 $('input, select, textarea').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val(),
       name = $(this).attr('name');
       localStorage[person + "." + name] = value;
       window.location.href = "Confirmation.html";
    console.log('stored key: '+name+' stored value: '+value);
});   
});
```

Here is the whole if helps show my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Axhn4/

Comment: Hospital/FName/LName only required atm per fiddle

Comment: seems its needs to validate first before the button click function runs if there is a way to accomplish that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe it is not related to your problem but in your "each" loop, you change the url of the page (**window.location.href = "Confirmation.html";**) so the page will be changed after analyzing the first input only.

Maybe you should remove this line outside the loop.

Comment: I've moved it around and seems to be the only place to work and still include storing/some validation.